# Adding a marker to a plot at specific points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe(first few rows):

[image]

I can plot it with `matplotlib.pyplot`:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,  ylabel='Price')

df1[['Close']].plot(ax=ax1)
```

To get:

[image]

What I would like to do is to add a marker to plot, down triangle, at the index `2018-09-10 04:00:00` which is indicated by the value `-1` in the position column of the dataframe.

I tried to do this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111,  ylabel='Price')

df1[['Close']].plot(ax=ax1)
ax1.plot(
    df1.loc[df1.positions == -1.0].index,
    df1.Close[df1.positions == -1.0],
    'v', markersize=5, color='k'
)
```

I get the plot like this:

[image]

So two things. One is that the index gets converted to something that shoots to year 2055, I don't understand why. Plus is there a way to add a marker at the specific position using just the first `plot` call? I tried to use `markevery` but with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to combine pandas plots and matplotlib datetime plots, the pandas plot needs to be plotted in compatibility mode

```
df1['Close'].plot(ax=ax1, x_compat=True)
```

That might give you the desired plot already.

If you don't want to use matplotlib, you can plot the filtered dataframe

```
df1['Close'].plot(ax=ax1)
df1['Close'][df1.positions == -1.0].plot(ax=ax1, marker="v", markersize=5, color='k')
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Both suggestions are working. I will use the `x_compat` as it is just creating the markers. I didn't realise that pandas and matplotlib plots are different.

Comment: Well the plots are of course not different. But pandas may decide to use different units to plot dates.